# Represent exponential express in terms of bit operators

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I'm trying to figure out how I would represent

```
x/2^y -> in terms of binary operators
```

I know

```
x >> 1 = = x/2
```

So my gut is saying that using what I know, there is some more manipulation needed in order to be able to represent. But I've been stuck for a while so I thought I might get some guidance here.

Comment: Did you mean `x / (2^y)`? Because x divided by 2^x is not a very interesting function.

Comment: Oh shoot, my bad. Yeah, exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Given that clarification, I think you want `x >> y;`

REVISED: The above only works for unsigned integers.

I can't figure out how to make it round signed numbers toward zero without using addition. Using signed 32-bit integers, the following works:

```
((x+(x>>31))>>y)-(x>>31)
```

This works because `x>>31` is -1 for negative numbers, zero for positive numbers.

Comment: Do you think you could give a bit of an explanation, if possible? I'm fairly new to the world of bit operators so it takes a bit longer for me to process what exactly is happening. Thanks!

Comment: The definition of the >> operator is that it produces the integer part of the value of (x / (2^y)). That also turns out to be the behaviour of bit-shifting in twos complement arithmetic; if you shift a number right by `y` bits, then the value of each remaining bit is reduced by `2^y`. The rightmost `y` bits are discarded (they would be the fractional part of the division).

Comment: Okay, that makes a lot more sense now. But there seems to be a problem with this route. For example if I wanted to do (-15)/(2^1) then answer should be -7 but its rather coming out as -8.

Comment: Try it again using unsigned integers. The example you gave rounded downwards, not towards zero.

Comment: How would I make it round toward zero? Because that's what I want. Unsigned numbers are working fine.